# Android - OkHttp - Tagging all network requests with TrafficStats

Tags: android, okhttp, android-networking

I'm trying to figure out specifically how much of my app's data use is being used by the requests I send with OkHttpClient, and I saw that I can use [TrafficStats](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html#setThreadStatsTag(int)) to tag a thread and then see it's network activity with the tag.

if I do something like

```
TrafficStats.setThreadStatsTag(1234);
okHttpClient.execute(request);
```

then it actually tags it okay(ish), but then when I use the async method (`okHttpClient.enqueue(request)`) it doesn't (which is kinda obvious though I hoped they'd have support for that).

So I tried a couple of things:

- Setting a dispatcher for the client where it's a normal dispatcher which basically on every execute replaces the Runnable it receives with a new runnable that first tags the thread an then runs the original runnable - some traffic was tagged but a lot wasn't.
- Setting a socket factory which basically tags every socket it produces - still some some traffic tagged but most of it wasn't.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I think TrafficStats.setThreadStatsTag() is for thread, so maybe we can add an interceptor for okhttp client.

```
private static class TrafficStatInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    int mTrafficTag;

    TrafficStatInterceptor(int trafficTag) {
        mTrafficTag = trafficTag;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        if (mTrafficTag > 0) {
            TrafficStatUtils.setThreadStatsTag(mTrafficTag);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "invalid traffic tag " + mTrafficTag);
        }
        return chain.proceed(chain.request());
    }
}
```

then just add this interceptor

```
OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
client.addNetworkInterceptor(new TrafficStatInterceptor(trafficTag));
```

Comment: From where is the `TrafficStatUtils`?

Comment: @StefanKuppelwieser I used `android.net.TrafficStats.setThreadStatsTag(trafficTag)`

Answer (score 1):

It’s difficult to do generally because with HTTP/2 sockets are shared across requests. With HTTP/1.1 they’re reused. Your best bet will be to write a [network interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) to tag the current thread. That’ll handle all HTTP/1.1 traffic and outgoing HTTP/2 traffic. There’s currently no API to access the thread that reads incoming HTTP/2 traffic.

Comment: yeah, I tried an interceptor it worked better than the other methods but also wasn't very accurate :/
Do you know of a good way to count bytes from the Request/Response objects in the interceptor ? (I can get body length easily but then need to also count the URL, method and headers and I'm worried that it'll end up not accurate enought)

Comment: You might be able to do it with a custom SocketFactory and Socket class.